# how to figure out the HSQLDB version of a given JBoss instance

Tags: jboss, version, hsqldb

Any way is fine - console, web interface, programmatically...
I was unable to find the DB version in the web interface yet and even the jars in the {$JBOSS_HOME}/common/lib don't have the version in the filename.
The JBoss version is 5.1 EAP
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to where the HSQLDB database is stored:

```
{$JBOSS_HOME}/Server/XXX/data/hypersonic
```

and open the localDB.properties file, at the top it will have the version, like this:

```
#HSQL Database Engine 1.8.0.8
```

Comment: Found it. Thank you, William Lannen. I would never have looked there.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no database properties file handy, try unzipping `hsqldb.jar`, and looking in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file for something like this:

```
Specification-Version: 1.8.0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also [detect the HSQLDB version using SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/2021/05/12/how-to-get-an-rdbms-server-version-with-sql/)

```sql
select character_value
from information_schema.sql_implementation_info
where implementation_info_name = 'DBMS VERSION'
```